# Popup makes the EditText lose focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want a popup (a callout) to be on the screen when my application starts. Clicking on anything should cause the popup disappear.

I am making it appear using this piece of code in onCreate() -

```
findViewById(R.id.anchor_button).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         SecondActivity.this.showPopupToolTip(findViewById(R.id.anchor_button), "Sample Text");
    }
});
```

and my showPopupToolTip function is as follows -

```
protected void showPopupToolTip(View findViewById, String string) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_tooltip1, null);
        view.setText(string);

        toolTopPopup = new PopupWindow(view, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        toolTopPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        toolTopPopup.setTouchable(true);
        toolTopPopup.setFocusable(false);
        toolTopPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        toolTopPopup.setAnimationStyle(0);

        toolTopPopup.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                Log.e("HELLO", "On Dismiss called");

            }
        });

        toolTopPopup.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                SecondActivity.this.toolTopPopup.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });

        toolTopPopup.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.anchor_button), 0, 0);
    }
```

The popup appears. But when i press the EditText field the keyboard slides in but whatever I type will not appear in my EditText field. What is wrong?

In case it helps, this is my activity layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/anchor_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="H" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_field"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you got the solution of this problem ? Please share if you find the solution.

Comment: I used a `Dialog` instead of `PopupWindow` to make this work.

Comment: thanks for reply i have solved this issue by customization in PopupWindow

Comment: @NaveenKumar i am also getting same problem.. can you help me?

Comment: I used a dialog instead of Popup. That helped.

Comment: Hope I'm not too late, when initializing PopUpWindow, setFocusable(false) , it will work fine